# I'm getting value as an object when i'm returing a value from handlebars. How to get the inside value

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

> Output of these console.log is  Settlement data for resubmit is =
>       [object Object] When data is stringifyed the we get     = "[object
>       Object]" Settlement data for resubmit is = [object Object] When data
>       is stringifyed the we get     = {"Record":"[object Object]"}
>       but we want data from inside the settleFight (complete data of settleFight):

```
JSON is like this: 
"Data": [
    {
        "Key": "HELLOWORLD1234",
        "settleFight": {
            "ATransfers": [
                {
                    "From": "Delhi",
                    "To": "Mumbai",
                    "ID": "ACK1994",
                    "Qty": "900",
                }
            ],
            "LastUpdatedTimestamp": "2018-05-01 10:30:06.91983248 +0000 UTC",
            "ObjectType": "SETTLEMENT",
            "Reason": "FIGHT",
            "SettlementStatus": "FAILED",
            "SettlementType": "FORCED",
            "Version": 1
        }
    }
]




  <script>
    window.reSettle = function (SettlData){ 
         console.log(" Settlement data for resubmit is = " + SettlData);         
console.log("When data is stringifyed the we get = " + JSON.stringify(SettlData));
      var valueS= {}; valueS = {"Record": SettlData}; 
     console.log(" Settlement data for resubmit is = " + valueS);
     console.log("When data is stringifyed the we get     = " +
     JSON.stringify(valueS)); 
     console.log("When data is PARSed the we get
     = " + JSON.parse(valueS)); 
    </script> 
    <body> 
    <div style="cursor:pointer; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;"
     onclick="reSettle('{{settleFight}}');">Resettle</div> 
    </body>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are your expectations?

Comment: want to get the data of settleFight in a JS file further processing and function and i also need that data to render other template data table with settleFight data.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you'll find below a snippet that uses your data with two examples that you may find useful.

You have to use {{#each}} to iterate on your array data. The context in an each loop is the data passed to the each loop so use {{ID}} if you pass ATransfers. Another way of doing it without iterating on your array is to use the direct notation {{Data.0.settleFight.ATransfers.0.ID}} where 0 is the occurence in the array. I would personally not recommend using this notation because it would fail if the array has no element and you won't understand why.

Another remark : in your example you don't use your arrays as you have only one element into them. If they're not mandatory you can simplify your data using :

```
var context = { "Data": [
    {
        "Key": "HELLOWORLD1234",
        "settleFight": {
           "ATransfers": {
                    "From": "Delhi",
                    "To": "Mumbai",
                    "ID": "ACK1994",
                    "Qty": "900",
            },
            "LastUpdatedTimestamp": "2018-05-01 10:30:06.91983248 +0000 UTC",
            "ObjectType": "SETTLEMENT",
            "Reason": "FIGHT",
            "SettlementStatus": "FAILED",
            "SettlementType": "FORCED",
            "Version": 1
        }
     }
  }
```

If you do so you'll have no need of {{#each}} and you'll may use {{Data.settleFight.ATransfers.ID}}

```js
var obj = { "Data": [
    {
        "Key": "HELLOWORLD1234",
        "settleFight": {
            "ATransfers": [
                {
                    "From": "Delhi",
                    "To": "Mumbai",
                    "ID": "ACK1994",
                    "Qty": "900",
                }
            ],
            "LastUpdatedTimestamp": "2018-05-01 10:30:06.91983248 +0000 UTC",
            "ObjectType": "SETTLEMENT",
            "Reason": "FIGHT",
            "SettlementStatus": "FAILED",
            "SettlementType": "FORCED",
            "Version": 1
        }
    }
] };

var source   = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = template(obj);

function deleteBill(bill) {
  console.log(bill);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
First example (only direct access)
<div style="cursor:pointer; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;"
     onclick="reSettle('{{Data.0.settleFight.ATransfers.0.ID}}');">Resettle {{Data.0.settleFight.ATransfers.0.ID}}</div> 


Second example (mix with each and direct access)
{{#each Data}}
   <div style="cursor:pointer; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;"
     onclick="reSettle('{{settleFight.ATransfers.0.ID}}');">Resettle {{settleFight.ATransfers.0.ID}}</div> 
{{/each}}

Second example (only each loops):
{{#each Data}}
  {{#each settleFight.ATransfers}}
   <div style="cursor:pointer; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;"
     onclick="reSettle('{{ID}}');">Resettle {{ID}}</div> 
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```